# What are all the known lightsaber designs?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

What are the different designs of lightsabers in the Star Wars canon? For example, Darth Maul with his double-bladed saber, and Kylo Ren with his cross-guard saber.

Comment: Something called the "Shoto" or something, not sure if it is canon, but it is a little tiny lightsaber, used in the off-hand, or as the main lightsaber if you're Yoda.

Comment: Don't forget Dooku's curved one http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dooku's_lightsaber

Comment: Are you looking for different **visual designs** or **engineering designs**? Most lightsabers except for a couple had the same engineering one.

Comment: What would be visual vs engineering?

Comment: I'm thinking of differences like that of the two I mentioned in the question. Also, Yoda's and Dooku's as mentioned above. They are very different from the traditional "simple" style.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

### Canon

- Vanilla lightsabers:

  [image]
- Double-bladed lightsaber (see: Darth Maul, Pong Krell, Savage Oppress)

  [image]

  - While I hesitate to call this a completely different style, Master Krell's lightsabers are unique in at least one way: they fold up

    [image]

    This is no longer quite as unique as I thought; in the *Star Wars: Rebels* episode "Shroud of Darkness", Kanan duels with a Force Vision of a Jedi Temple Guard, who uses a folding saber.
- Curved-hilt lightsabers, like Dooku's:

  [image]
- Asajj Ventress' lightsaber(s)

  [image]

  Ventress wielded two curved-hilt lightsabers. In *The Clone Wars* animated film, she was able to combine them into a single, S-shaped double-bladed lightsaber:

  [image]

  However, Obi-Wan Kenobi possibly destroys the mechanism that allows this during his fight with Ventress in the film; he cuts her (connected) lightsaber in half, and we never see her use the technique in *The Clone Wars* show.
- Lightsaber pike, used by the Jedi Temple Guards<sup>1</sup>:

  [image]

  We have a close encounter with a Temple Guard in "Shroud of Darkness", a *Star Wars: Rebels* episode, where Kanan has a duel with (a Force ghost of) one using a folding lightsaber. It's not apparent whether this is a standard Guard's saber or not, but there is the reasonable possibility that these sabers do fold.
- Crossguard lightsaber, most famously used by Kylo Ren:

  [image]

  But also in use by ancient Jedi; Ezra Bridger finds a crossguard saber on the Sith world of Malachor, a relic of an ancient battle:

  [image]
- Shoto (a shorter hilt, used by smaller Jedi like Yoda and Even Piell)

  [image]

  Shotos are also used by the rare dual-wielding Jedi as an off-hand lightsaber; in the below image from *The Clone Wars*, you can clearly see that one saber is dramatically shorter than the other:

  [image]

  I regret that I do not know what episode this image is from; I welcome input from anyone who does.
- Sabercane (Cane/lightsaber combo), used by Master Tera Sinube:

  [image]
- Lightsaber/blaster combo (invented by Ezra Bridger, apparently)

  [image]
- Darksaber

  [image]
- Inquisitor's lightsaber:

  [image]

  Not merely a double-bladed lightsaber with a funky grip, the saber style used by the Imperial Inquisitors spins around that central ring. The image above is of the Grand Inquisitor, from season 1 of *Rebels*, but we've seen the other inquisitors in season 2 using sabers of the same style
- Debated whether or not to include this, but Kanan Jarrus' lightsaber exhibited a property we've never seen before:

  [image]

  It comes apart into two pieces. There a bunch of things we don't know about this lightsaber, including whether the pieces function without being connected, or if this is something all lightsabers can do but we've never seen before, but it's an otherwise unique property

### Legends

Most of the above, plus:

- Guard shoto (or Lightsaber tonfa)

  [image]
- Long-handled lightsaber:

  [image]
- One-bladed variant on the lightsaber pike:

  [image]
- Whatever you call this thing:

  [image]

  Thunderforge, in comments, suggests three-bladed lightsaber because there of the third blade in the middle of the handle. Wookieepedia calls it the ["War Dragon rider lightsaber"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/War_Dragon_rider), because its only appearance in any material is a "design an alien" contest in *Star Wars Galaxy Magazine*. The War Dragon Rider actually won the contest, no doubt because it looks like something a Space-metalhead would have airbrushed on the side of his spacevan.
- Lightwhip

  [image]
- Forked lightsaber

  [image]
- I believe Ventress' lightsabers were also slightly more interesting in Legends; in addition to the weirdness stated above, I believe she could tie them together with cord and whirl them around like nunchaku; I can't recall seeing this in canon, but I'm happy to be corrected.
- Protosaber/Retrosaber

  [image]

  The earliest true lightsabers are now typically called retrosabers; their distinguishing feature was an external powerpack, typically worn on the belt and connected to the hilt by a cord.

  After the Jedi went wireless, protosaber look-alikes were called "retrosabers," which also used the external power source, and continued to be used by Jedi hispters the galaxy over (the above image is from an RPG sourcebook set during the Clone Wars)
- Forcesaber

  [image]

  The earliest iteration of the lightsaber was called the Forcesaber; it was used by the Force Hounds, Force-sensitive hunters used by the Rakatan Infinite Empire to find worlds with lots of Force-sensitive inhabitants (which the Rakatans would then invade and enslave). The main difference between the Forcesaber and a lightsaber is one of engineering: rather than requiring a battery, the Forcesaber is activated by channelling Dark Side energy through the hilt.

---

<sup>1</sup> My first instinct was to classify these as double-bladed lightsabers, but they have [their own entry in the Databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank/lightsaber-pike), so ho-hum

Comment: Where is the lightwhip from? Seems pretty different from the rest as lightsabers are generally considered rigid. Also, it looks massively OP :)

Comment: @DavidGrinberg That particular image is from one of the *Jedi vs. Sith* comics, but there have been a few users throughout Legends; Lumiya is probably the best-known example

Comment: As for the one that isn't able to be classified, note that there is a third blade in the middle of the handle, unlike Darth Maul's double-bladed one which had a long handle. Maybe call it a three-bladed lightsaber?

Comment: @Thunderforge Looks like a [D&D4 Quarterstaff](http://dnd4.wikia.com/wiki/Quarterstaff)

Comment: @Izkata Could be, since D&D 4e was built off of the rule set of the Star Wars: Saga Edition RPG. I think it's more of a coincidence though.

Comment: What does that 3-bladed one look like when switched off?  Are the two handles still connected?  That seems wildly impractical...

Comment: Great answer! The *Rebels* ones aren't Legends though.

Comment: @RogueJedi It took me an embarrassingly long time to figure out what you were talking about; you're right, I was not thinking when I added that

Comment: Would the saber from The Force Unleashed that can channel and shoot force lightning be considered an additional style?

Comment: @user2989297 I haven't played *The Force Unleashed*, so I don't know. I don't think so, though; Mace Windu was able to reflect Force Lightning with his normal lightsaber, so unless the technique used is radically different from that, I wouldn't expect so

Comment: @JasonBaker https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-g2SAuXCHN0. I could have sworn this one made an appearance, and it didn't deflect force lightning. The wielder could channel their force lightning into the saber and it would shoot the lightning out of the spikes when extended. I could be totally wrong though. I used to own this. That's why I remembered it.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman The three-bladed lightsaber only appears in [one picture](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/War_Dragon_rider) that won first place in the [Design an Alien](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Design_An_Alien) contest for Star Wars Galaxy magazine, with part of the prize being that it was canon (now Legends canon). Since the lightsaber doesn't exist beyond that picture, we don't know what it would look like turned off.

Comment: To your `1` footnote: the saber pike seems to have shorter blades than the double-bladed saber, which I guess must be significant enough to cause this distinction.

Comment: How about adding a picture of Ashoka Tano's single-handed short blades she uses in the *Clone Wars* and *Rebels* TV series? And what about Youngling Gungi's lightsaber he builds in the *Clone Wars* episode "The Gathering"? Its outer casing is **wood**! (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rDCNUWAobl4)

Comment: @RemyLebeau I wouldn't classify either of those as being radically different from what's been presented here. I don't think Ahsoka's lightsabers were any smaller than normal ones (if they were, then shotos are already covered). Gungi's saber, notwithstanding material (which wouldn't have had any significant effect on the functioning of the saber) was just a regular single-bladed saber

Comment: In relation to Kanan's lightsaber, it comes apart because the two pieces aren't supposed to look like a lightsaber seperately. It's still unclear whether or not it works in two parts, but I shouldn't think so.

Comment: +1 for *looks like something a Space-metalhead would have airbrushed on the side of his spacevan*

Comment: @user2989297 Now that I've played *The Force Unleashed* to the end, it seems like there's nothing particularly special about Starkiller's lightsaber; the player can infuse their lightsaber with Force Lightning for some combos, but it doesn't seem like that's a special property of the saber's construction. The one in the video you linked looks like the Sith Assassin Starkiller's saber (from the DLC), which seems to differ from the others only cosmetically. I feel confident in leaving it off

Comment: @JasonBaker That comment happened 2 years ago. I think it is epic that you rounded back on that. I wont fully reengage the point, but myself, I would include the nature of DLC less in my analysis, and more ask what a 'design' is. My example is a hilt built to conduct lightning. To be used by a heavy lightning user. The same lightning ability might be usable for a non-pronged saber user in the game, but that doesnt necessarily discount a saber built to conduct electricity, which does exist in teh Sith Assassin Starkiller's saber.

Comment: For the non-canon lightsabers, some concept art for Plo Koon has him using a [wrist-mounted device](http://theoriginallightsaber.com/Conceptual/ROTS/PloKi.jpg) like a katar or Halo energy sword.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of lightsabers:

- Double-sided: a lightsaber with blades on both sides. Some can be taken apart into dual 
  lightsabers. Some models can fold up. Typically longer than a normal lightsaber. Can be 
  used as a long-handled single bladed lightsaber. Some notable examples of use were by 
  Asajj Ventress, Darth Maul, Pong Krell, and Jedi Temple 
  Guards.
- Dual: Two lightsabers, normally alike. Some can be put together to make a double sided 
  lightsaber. Some notable examples of use were by Asajj Ventress, Ahsoka Tano, 
  Starkiller, and Anakin Skywalker (just for a short time on the Trade Federation Control 
  Ship).
- Crossguard: A single-bladed lightsaber with two mini-blades protruding from each side 
  of the handle, normally making it slightly longer than normal. Better for blocking 
  enemies with more saber range. A notable example of use was by Kylo Ren, though a few 
  ancient Jedi and many ancient Sith used them.
- Shoto: A shorter version of the lightsaber, with the handle a few inches shorter and 
  around a 2 1/2 - 2 foot long blade. Some notable examples of use were by Ahsoka Tano 
  and Yoda.
- Lightwhip: A type of single blade lightsaber except the blade was like a whip, so only 
  extremely skilled Jedi or Sith could wield it without killing themselves. I don't know of 
  anyone who uses them, though.
- Spinning: A double sided lightsaber that can spin on a track built into the handle, so 
  it basically spins automatically. It can be used as a single-bladed spinning 
  lightsaber, though, too. Some notable examples of use were by The First through 
  Thirteenth Sisters (Estimate) and the First through Thirteenth Brothers (Also 
  estimate).
- Dual-Phase: A lightsaber that uses two Kyber Crystals, therefor being twice as long. 
  Some dual-phase lightsabers can be switched between 3 feet and 6 feet. I don't know of 
  any users of this blade.
- Curved hilt: A lightsaber with a curved hilt, enabling much more maneuverability. 
  Sometimes used as dual and dual curved hilts can be combined to make a double-sided 
  blade with an S-shaped handle.
- Blaster-Saber: A lightsaber with a blaster attached, enabling you to have a compact 
  weapon. A notable use of this type was by Ezra Bridger.
- Underwater-Saber: Most lightsabers short out when they touch water, but underwater 
  sabers don't. The only known one was used by Kit Fisto.
- Lightsaber Pike: A type of lightsaber, typically with a very long hilt, long than a 
  double sided hilt, and sometimes a longer or shorter blade. I believe some Jedi Temple 
  Guards used them.
- Darksaber: A lightsaber with a rectangular prism hilt instead of a cylindrical hilt. 
  The blade is shaped like a sword's blade, and is a black flecked with white color.
- Normal single bladed: Most Jedi and Sith use this. It's in balance with all the pros 
  and cons.

There are others that I haven't covered here, but I believe I got most of them.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

That thing right there idk if you can see it or not

Oh and also saber clubs. They were just REALLY big lightsabers. Like something chewie would have used if ya know, the force was with him or whatever.

Comment: Is any of this canonical? I've seen/read quite a bit of the canon things and haven't really come across the club.