# Which weapons can stand against a Lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

We know as a fact that a lightsaber can be stopped during a fight by another lightsaber. Also I remember two more Imperial weapons that were able to stop a lightsaber:

1. the Z6 riot control baton
2. a weapon I saw being used by the robot protectors of General Grievous. I think it's the same weapon that Rey is using in *The Force Awakens*.

**Do we know of any other similar *weapons* that can fight against a lightsaber?**

Comment: Canon or legends?

Comment: @Obie Always a canon is appreciated but if there is nothing legends woulddo as well i guess...

Comment: the one used by the stormtrooper is known as the [Z6 Riot Control Baton](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Z6_riot_control_baton). Other examples have been seen in games such as the Force Unleashed series, and appear to operate in a similar manner to the above.

Comment: Out-of-universe, lightsaber combat is not surprisingly written, blocked, and filmed kind of like saber/sword combat. If we think about that analogy, what **weapons** "can fight against" a regular sword, besides another sword? Basically, other hand weapons that are design just for that task, like sai. Going back in-universe, there are probably very few other **weapons** designed to "fight against" a lightsaber, because what would be better against a lightsaber than another lightsaber? Or just armor if you're not a jedi?

Comment: @ToddWilcox and by the way, i didnt ask for weapons specifically made to fight against a lightsaber, i just asked if there are other examples of weapons like the two i mentioned (and which i dont think they were made for the specific reason to fight a lightsaber) that can fight against a lightsaber, which actually if you think of it means, if there is something that wont be cut in half if a lightsaber hits it, for example you cannot use the broom you have in your house cause it would be cut in half.... get me now?

Comment: @ToddWilcox btw even a fork can go against a sword..... you just need to know how to use it...

Comment: Makes sense about the fork. Isn't "fork" also an answer to your question? Again, assuming you know how to use it. You could throw the fork (possibly with help from the Force) and hit the power stud on a lightsaber. Or you could deftly wedge the fork in between your enemy's hand and their lightsaber and disarm them. Or stab with the fork at just the right angle to damage/dislodge the crystal in the lightsaber. Good answer, I think you should post it.

Comment: @Skooba thanks for the comment man, but i already know of that had it mentioned on the post, i mention it as a "modern glop", ill just edit the name...

Comment: @ToddWilcox no it isnt, a fork could maybe stop a shord, but against a lightsaber it would be cut in half....  you get what i am trying to say here? now you are just trolling.....

Comment: @Valorum look at that beautiful answer of Rogue Jedi and tell me if you knew all of them, if you didnt then you learned two usefull things today, i guess you understand.

Comment: In the Xbox game Star Wars Obi Wan a group called the Jin Ha (maybe wrong spelling) use weapons which beat lightsabers.

Comment: @hedgehog I don't think so.

Comment: Hokey religions and ancient weapons are no match for a good blaster at your side.

Comment: No weapon can stand on its own. They must be held.

Comment: @MarkMeuer you speak like a real stormtrooper.... The First Order would be glad to have you :p

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Canon:

- Other [lightsabers](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lightsaber)
- [Z6 riot control batons](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Z6_riot_control_baton)
- [Electrostaffs](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Electrostaff)
- The [darksaber](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darksaber)

### Legends:

- Any weapon made from [Cortosis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cortosis/Legends)
- Lightsabers and the various lightsaber [variants](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111589/51226)
- Any weapon made from [Phrik](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Phrik/Legends), including Electrostaffs
- Any weapon made from [Songsteel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Songsteel)
- Any weapon made from [Mandalorian Iron](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mandalorian_iron)
- [Force Weapons](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_weapon)
- [Amphistaffs](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Amphistaff)

Comment: see gWaldos answer and if it legit add the "Sith Sword" in  your answer as well to have them all listed together :)

Comment: You can add Beskar Spear to the canon answers https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Beskar_spear

Answer (score 6):

Any weapon crafted using a [**Cortosis-weave**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cortosis-weave) could withstand a lightsaber wielding opponent.

There are references in *Knights of the Old Republic* game to the cortosis-weave technique in the making of weapons. I don't believe there is any specific movie canon reference to anti-lightsaber technology

Comment: I didnt talk about anti lightsaber technology, just weapons that can counter attack a lightsaber...... not directly built for fighting lightsabers i mean.....

Comment: Clarification:  By anti lightsaber technology I meant technology that could withstand lightsabers in battle

Comment: i know what u meant, i am just saying that at least for these two weapons i mentioned i know that they were not specifically made for fight against lightsabers just happened that they could be used against them. anyways, do we know or have we seen other weapons that can be used against a lightsaber?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @Rogue Jedi's fantastic answer, the race of Sith also produced weapons capable of deflecting lightsabers.

[Sith Sword](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith_sword)

Answer (score 1):

I’m going to list *specific* weapons by their effectiveness against a lightsaber in combat:

The Laser Scalpel. It most likely utilizes similar plasma tech to that of a lightsaber, but you’d be screwed fighting with one in most cases.

The Laser Knife. It’s basically a lightsaber in the shape of a small knife. Unlike the laser scalpel, most people used it in combat, and it behaved quite like a lightsaber would.

Stun batons/electro-batons: Most stun batons probably wouldn’t be able to penetrate the armor of a storm trooper, but some can do some real damage/block lightsabers.

Neuronic whips. Torture devices in the form of electric whips. Unpredictable, but it might work against an unskilled lightsaber wielder.

The Blastsword. It’s a blaster you have to hit someone with, but I doubt you could *actually* properly defend yourself against a Jedi with.

Electroswords. This one really depends on what they’re made of. Some can actually block lightsabers, but others cannot.

Power lances. I doubt these could really *block* a lightsaber, but they’re so ridiculously huge that if you were to charge at a lightsaber wielder with one on a speederbike, it could pose a serious challenge for them.

Energy lances. These can shoot out energy beams so I think that might distract a lightsaber-wielding foe long enough for a good blow.

Felucian Skullblades. These can actually consistently defend against a lightsaber, so its probably a good idea to have this one as your first pick above the ones listed previously.

Electrowhips/shock whips. These things are really only used for torture, but they can consistently block lightsaber attacks. The downside is that using these weapons is quite hard, and they can also be unpredictable. But that might work to your advantage against a lightsaber-wielder.

Electrostaffs. Walmart grade lightsabers, but they can definitely block lightsabers and make life difficult for whoever is faced against them. So long as they’re made of Phrik, that is.

Force pikes. A better version of the energy and power lances; these things can consistently block lightsabers and are very effective against them.

Praetorian guard weapons: Unless you’re in a Star Wars sequel trilogy movie, you actually have a decent chance of defeating a lightsaber with one.

Force imbued blades/any Sith or Jedi artifact: Some of these are arguably BETTER than a lightsaber!

Lightfoils: Lightsabers for non-force wielders. Enough said.

Amphistaff: Living creatures that eat lightsabers for lunch.

Comment: You could improve this answer by editing it to include some evidence or sources to support the assertions you've made here.